# Merge two dataframes based on new column(s) values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `Dataframes`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["1", "3", "22", "43"],
        "B": ["6", "19", "4", "31"],
        "C": ["47", "15", "8", "19"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["65", "47", "6", "13"],
        "B": ["29", "5", "2", "21"],
        "C": ["69", "9", "11", "80"],
    },
    index=[4, 5, 6, 7],
)
```

By using `pandas`, the **final result** should be:

```
    A   B   C   Ti  ID
0   1   6   47  am  01
1   3   19  15  am  01
2   22  4   8   am  01
3   43  31  19  am  01
4   65  29  69  pm  01
5   47  5   9   pm  01
6   6   2   11  pm  01
7   13  21  80  pm  01
```

I went through [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), and I am trying to merge these two `Dataframes` by using `pd.concat`. The code is:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['am', 'pm']).reset_index()
```

However, the new `Dataframe` came out with an extra column `level_1` that I don't want it to be there:

```
    level_0  level_1  A    B    C
0   am       0        1    6    47
1   am       1        3    19   15
2   am       2        22   4    8
3   am       3        43   31   19
4   pm       4        65   29   69
5   pm       5        47   5    9
6   pm       6        6    2    11
7   pm       7        13   21   80
```

I know `reset_index()` created that unwanted column. But why?

What else to do to get the same **final `Dataframe`** using `pandas`?

Comment: Why reset_index() created an extra column? And the solution should not get rid of all the columns. the column level_0 and its values are fine but level_1 is extra and unwanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you concatenate the DataFrames,

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['am', 'pm'])
```

`new_df` looks like

```
       A   B   C
am 0   1   6  47
   1   3  19  15
   2  22   4   8
   3  43  31  19
pm 4  65  29  69
   5  47   5   9
   6   6   2  11
   7  13  21  80
```

If we look at the index `new_df.index`, it's a MultiIndex where the first level is the keys and second level is the old index:

```
MultiIndex([('am', 0),
            ('am', 1),
            ('am', 2),
            ('am', 3),
            ('pm', 4),
            ('pm', 5),
            ('pm', 6),
            ('pm', 7)],
           )
```

Then first we can rename the MultiIndex levels using `rename_axis`, and `reset_index` but only remove the first level from the index (which then becomes a column with its name). Note that by default, `reset_index` removes all levels from the index. That's why you see `level_0` and `level_1` columns added after `reset_index`.

```
new_df = new_df.rename_axis(['Ti', None]).reset_index(level=0)
```

You can rearrange the columns by reassigning the DataFrame with a list of the columns with the desired order.

```
cols = new_df.columns.tolist()
new_df = new_df[cols[1:]+[cols[0]]]
new_df['ID'] = '01'
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C  Ti  ID
0   1   6  47  am  01
1   3  19  15  am  01
2  22   4   8  am  01
3  43  31  19  am  01
4  65  29  69  pm  01
5  47   5   9  pm  01
6   6   2  11  pm  01
7  13  21  80  pm  01
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! Could the "Ti" column set to the end after column "C" in the same script `new_df = new_df.rename_axis(['Ti','']).reset_index(level=0)`?

Comment: @BigBadBroBot You can change the column order like: `new_df = new_df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'Ti']]`

Comment: @SangkeunPark that works too :-)

Answer (score 0):

When reset_index() is used, it adds the old index as a column in the dataframe. You can set drop = True to drop the old indexes:

```
reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution will get rid of the new column I would like to add (level_0) which should be (Ti) in the final result that I want to get. I can easily say `new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simpler solution to me.

```
df1['Ti'] = 'am'
df2['Ti'] = 'pm'

new_def = df1.append(df2)
```